# MonoGame: problem with rendering 3d model and spritebatch

Tags: c#, 3d, render, monogame, spritebatch

I want to draw some debug info on screen, but this cause problem with rendering model. I found some solutions in the internet, but it dosen't work. Maybe i'm too stupid, but i don't know what's wrong.
Here's Draw method:

```
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.DarkCyan);

        spriteBatch.Begin();
        player.Draw(dt);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(gamefont, "render Time :" + gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds, new Vector2(0, 85), Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();

        effect.View = player.view;
        effect.Projection = player.projection;
        effect.Texture = dirtTexture;

        GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.PointClamp;
        GraphicsDevice.BlendState = BlendState.Opaque;
        GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;

        foreach (EffectPass p in effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
        {
            p.Apply();
            effect.World = player.world;
            GraphicsDevice.DrawPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, buffer.VertexCount / 3);
        }



        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

[Here how it look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiTbk.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drawing a 2D HUD messes up rendering of my 3D models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14938832/drawing-a-2d-hud-messes-up-rendering-of-my-3d-models)

Comment: As you can see, i reset depth buffer, so this isn't the problem. There is something else, but i can't get what.

Comment: What is the issue with output?

Comment: I added image to description. I don't know why it's happaen. I used brakepoint to check values of GraphicsDevice, but i didn't find changes at moment of drawing 3d model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Triangles normals (the forward face) are being drawn backwards. This is defined by the order of the vertices in the vertexbuffer.

Luckily, we can specify the order in the `GraphicsDevice`. Just add the line:

```
GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = RasterizerState.CullCounterClockwise;
```

If that gives the same result use:

```
GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = RasterizerState.CullClockwise;
```

Comment: Thanks. It helps. Plus before i created model with setting verteces itself, but now i created model and with GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = RasterizerState.CullCounterClockwise; it render correctly.

Comment: Just to be clear, that was the third line of the things to check under the linked post. I am glad it helped.